# What are the lengths of the two line segments into which the chord divides the diameter?

Tags: geometry

Imagine a circle of a diameter of length 70. A chord of length 42 intersects this diameter. What are the lengths of the two line segments into which the chord divides the diameter?

What? So is the chord going horizontal or verticle? I tried dividing 70 in half and subtracting 42 but neither was the answer. Can I get a little help?

Comment: Not clear as stated, so we'll assume that it is perpendicular.

Comment: A picture would help. Also, what is the angle between the 2 lines? Are they perpendicular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question does not have a definite solution without the angle at which the two chords intersect, so I will assume here that they are perpendicular to each other. Then by the intersecting chords theorem
$$21^2=441=x(70-x)$$
where 21 is of course half of 42, the shorter chord being bisected. Solving gives $x=7$ and $x=63$, so the diameter is divided into segments of those lengths.